# How to set the dark mode as default. Here I am trying to set the mode by using useState

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react.js project. And I want to set the dark mode as default. So whenever someone will open my page the dark mode should appear first. But I couldn't set the initial value in useState for the default dark mode.

```
    const [mode, setMode] = useState('Dark'); // Wether dark mode is enable or not

   // Toggle mode will effect after clicking the Dark mode or Li9ght mode
  const toggleMode = () => {
    if (mode === 'dark') {
      setMode('light');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
      document.title = 'News Monk - Light Mode';
    
    }
    else {
      setMode('dark');
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#283037';
      document.title = 'News Monk - Dark Mode';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Be careful with the CamelCase of 'Dark', because in the if else statement you are using 'dark', you can apply also the document.body in the useEffect when component loads

Answer (score 0):

You should be consistent with the cases, maybe always use "dark" and not "Dark"
`const [mode, setMode] = useState('dark');`